# Q: Insert data into loop statement

Tags: php, sql, insert

Good morning,

I'd hate to bother you all with what may be the simplest question/solution of all, but it appears that no matter what current articles I've read on stack overflow or even my own attempts at a resolution I can't seem to have the response I'm looking for.

What i've been trying to work on this whole week was being able to obtain the User ID (uid) from an invoice list and then insert that same ID over to a new table called convo_sent, problem is that the following code (shown below) doesn't insert the content more than once when there is more than one string to pull from within invoice_id:

SQL Table(s):

```
**invoices** table.

Id | uid  | invoice_id
1  |  2   | 1     
2  |  20  | 3
3  |  4   | 10
4  |  60  | 1    


**convo_sent** table.

Id | uid  | sid  | action       | action_id | date | seen
1  |  1   | 90   |  sent        |     1     |  n/a | 1
2  |  10  | 85   |  sent        |     1     |  n/a | 0
3  |  7   | 270  |  no_payment  |     0     |  n/a | 0
4  |  6   | 400  |  sent        |     1     |  n/a | 1
```

Script in question:

```
 $sql="select uid from invoices where invoice_id = '1'";
 $res=mysql_query($sql);
 while($data_set=mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
                $date=date("l, F j, Y h:i a", TIME());
                                    $sid=$_SESSION["mid"];
                                    $fid=$data_set["uid"];

                $sql="insert into convo_sent";
                $sql.="(uid";
                $sql.=", sid";
                $sql.=", action";
                $sql.=", action_id";
                $sql.=", seen";
                $sql.=", time)";

                $sql.=" values('$fid' ";
                $sql.=", '$sid'";
                $sql.=", 'test'";
                $sql.=", '0'";
                $sql.=", '0'";
                $sql.=", '$date')";
                $res = mysql_query($sql);
   $sr_no=$sr_no+1;
 }
```

What I believe happens is that although the statement (by itself, without the insert method) is able to loop through and pull the information I needed. When you're trying to use the insert method, perhaps the statement (looping) can only submit the first user ID and nothing else.

Comment: Where is `member_id` column in `invoices` table?

Comment: @Samir - Corrected the code, sorry. $data_set["uid"] replaces $data_set["member_id"] and $_SESSION["member_id"] is replaced by $_SESSION["mid"]; The code itself has been changed a bit from the original for easier understanding.

Comment: Do echo `$sql` and check how many times it loops inside `while`.

Comment: @Samir - Good question, will try it out.

Comment: @Samir - looped only once and it's always the last integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you override the select statement ($res variable). Replace $res variable into your loop.

```
$sql="select uid from invoices where invoice_id = '1'";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
while($data_set=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    // ...
    $sql="insert into convo_sent";
    // ...
    $status = mysql_query($sql);
    $sr_no=$sr_no+1;
}
```

Comment: @EqualPro - Annnd just like that, you managed to solve my problem. Thank you man!!

Comment: @EqualPro - Hey there, kind of came across something which I think you may have the answer for. To kind of summarize, I've been trying to use the mail() function to send messages to our clients regarding the invoices in question and it appears that those using outlook accounts are getting duplicate messages from within the same body template. I'm not sure how to proceed with resolving this.